# Oracle Forms - Identify which button was pressed

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I have an Oracle form, which when starts has the following activated field.
1. 2 text Item + 2 push button working as LOV button
2. One Button (cancel)

Now for simplicity lets call the text time as text_1 , text_2 
Now user has an option to enter any value in text_1 and either press TAB to move to next text item or use mouse pointer to move the cursor to text_2 item OR can press cancel button.

I want to know if the user has pressed TAB or used mouse to press cancel button.  Please let me know in case the question is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

if user presses tab key, forms generate `KEY-NEXT-ITEM` trigger. You can type your code there and manage this event. If users presses a button, forms generates `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED`.

Is this right answer to your question? If not, provide a use case, how will programm work from user point of view.

Answer (score 0):

if user presses tab key, forms generate KEY-NEXT-ITEM trigger and post-text-item trigger. Again if user move the cursor using mouse then it only generate post-text-item trigger. If any text item has to fire two trigger then key-next-item fires first.

You can also get triggered item using :SYSTEM.TRIGGER_ITEM.

Thanks
Shamim Ahmed.